# How turn to 404,when use wildcard like :id

Tags: react-router

When i use code like :

```
   <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/"  component={Home}/>
        <Route  path="/:category/:postId" component={Posts}/>
        <Route  path="/:category" component={Categories}/>
        <Route  path="/404" component={NotFound}/>
        <Redirect from="*" to="/404"/>
    </Switch>
```

it will not turn to 404 page when i turn to a wrong category path.I think it may  because :category can match it. How could i recognize the wrong category?Does 'if' work?

Comment: If you have an array of the _allowed_ catagories, an if statement works.  Could try to clearify exactly what your *issue* is?

Comment: Yes,i have an array of allowed category path---[react,redux,udacity].

Comment: Then check if the catagory is in that array, if so, go ahead loading that component, if not, redirect to */404*.

Comment: but the question is where i add the judge statement.before enter the page,i won't get the path.

Comment: @tulipij You have to do that _within_ your component, if it isn't a valid catagory, redirect to /404.

Comment: Thanks a lot.finally i resolve it.

Comment: the easier way would be to change your paths to `category/:category/:postId`

Comment: Yes,it's a easier way.thanks a lot.